# How to apply keyDown in Sikuli for common key

Tags: keydown, sikuli

I need Sikuli to hold a common key <kbd>f</kbd> but can't figure out how to do this.

```
keyDown(Key.F)
keyDown("f")
```

Doesn't work and tutorials are only about functional keys <kbd>Ctrs</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
But how to hold a common key?

Comment: did you find an answer to this? The answers below don't seem to be it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any key the same way you use functional keys. You can test it by trying the below code while your cursor is located in some text area and you will see that it performs "Select all" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>)

```
keyDown(Key.CTRL)
keyDown("a")
```

**EDIT**
If you want to repeat a key, try something like that:

```
for i in range(n):
    type("a")
```

where `n` is the number of times you want to type the letter

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it still doesn't work. I want to simulate pressed "a" key so in the notepad it will write this: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" until I stop script.

Comment: Well, this is not what you described in your question. Holding a key is different from repeating a key. Please see the amended answer.

Comment: This is game so key need to be hold, not pressed multiple times. I use: a = 0, while (a < 1): keyDown ("a") but this doesn't work.

Comment: I think you have to be a little bit more clear what you are tying to do. So you are using the "a" to move around in game? In your example you could also use while True: keyDown("a"). But if you have it in a game, maybe you don't  have focus on the game window.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows OS, and maybe others, interprets two or three subsequent calls to the same keyDown as holding a key down.

```
keyDown("f")
keyDown("f")
keyDown("f")
```

Answer (score 1):

To simulate a SELECT ALL, do this in SikuliX:

```
type("a", Key.CTRL)
```

Here is another way (older way):

```
type("a", KEY_CTRL)
```

Beware: There is a bug, where, for some computers, the NUM LOCK has to be turned off for the special CTRL commands to work.
Hope this helps!

Comment: you saved me <3 indeed the NUM LOCK was preventing me to use Key.SHIT modifier